# New Electrical outlets won’t fit flush to wall in pre fab remodel

Tags: electrical

[image: outlet]I am remodeling an old concrete pre fab house. The existing outlet holes are too shallow for a normal electrical outlet to fit flush to wall. Are there any products I can use that will help solve this? I’m in Costa Rica so I can’t just run over to Home Depot and check. Thinking maybe the US has more options of outlet depths? [image: electricaloutlet]

Comment: I'm not really understanding the problem.  Are you referring the the box holes not allowing the screws to go in all the way in?

Comment: I'm confused by the question - what you show in the pic is not what I'd refer to as a "normal electrical outlet". There's a lot of extra plastic all around your outlet which prevents it from being mounted flush against the box (like a "normal electrical outlet" should be able to). Is that the only style available to you or can you get something which looks more like [this](https://www.leviton.com/en/products/w5325-t0w)?

Comment: Or are you saying the box is too shallow for the outlet? (You may need to rearrange/rebend the wires a bit, if it's a small box.) Are you replacing an outlet, or was this prewired but never had an outlet here, or...

Comment: The back of the outlet won’t fit in the space available.

Comment: There was an outlet here, but it is very outdated and bulky

Answer (score 2):

### Use a Wiremold starter box

There are other types of extenders available, but the most elegant-ish type is going to be the starter boxes that are part of surface raceway systems (such as the Wiremold 500/700 series starters).  These should be available at your local electrical supply house, even if your local hardware/general construction suppliers don't carry them.

Comment: So you are saying I still will have to keep outlet outside of the wall? I can’t put it inside?

Comment: @Jet not unless you wish to completely replace the box in the wall with a deeper box

Comment: it’s a very old pre fab house in Costa Rica. It’s very shallow. The whole house is full of this problem and it looks terrible. Is there a product that just isn’t so thick?

Comment: @Jet -- you could try looking for a shallower/more conventional outlet, but it seems from your existing unit that you just don't have much box depth to play with

Comment: Fact. Do you think conventional outlets are more shallow? I don’t have a great selection here. The ones I’m finding are all about 2 inches deep then adding on the wires on top of that

Comment: I added a picture of what the outlets look like that fit flush to the walls here